# divide web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I am developing a asp.net project and I dont have very long web.config file yet(more then 400 lines). but with this nhibernate log4net and urlrewrites. its getting bigger and bigger. is there a proper way to divide web.config into pieces. like nhibernate.config and log4net.config ofcourse urlrewrite.config

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`system.webServer` is a configuration section **group** - you cannot externalize that.

You can only put the configSource= on a configuration **section** - e.g.

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation configSource="validation.config"/>
    <modules configSource="modules.config" />
    <handlers configSource="handlers.config" />
</system.webServer>
```

What is a configuration section group or a regular configuration section can only be determined by looking at the documentation for those things (and even then it's often not very easy to figure out whether it's a section or a section group :-( ).

Comment: I had the same problem with system.ServiceModel and it is indeed a Section group too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.configuration.servicemodelsectiongroup.aspx

Comment: The **runtime section** happily accepts the configSource attribute but it ***does not read the external file***

Answer (score 1):

This is possible by using the `configSource` attribute of root sections in the config file. This is actually a feature of the .NET configuration system so it can be done in any web or app config file.

Here is a [blog post](http://blog.andreloker.de/post/2008/06/16/Keep-your-config-clean-with-external-config-files.aspx) that describes this feature quite well.

Comment: I just tried that for system.webserver tag. it includes the urlrewrite mostly. and now I am getting "Unrecognized attribute 'configSource'"

Comment: Yes, that is a problem. system.webServer is not a standard config section itself. You should be able to use configSource on any of it's child elements however.